Docker file not copying env variables in sandbox
We are in the process of switching to Docker containers on our servers so we can easily scale up and down our server instances.
We are able to run the instance on prod and it be fine, however there are external issues preventing that switch. However on our feature branches, the builds all fail.
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# Client web

ARG NODE_VERSION=18.20.1
ARG PNPM_VERSION=8.6.10

################################################################################
# Use node image for base image for all stages.
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

# Set working directory for all build stages.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install pnpm.
RUN npm install -g pnpm@${PNPM_VERSION}

################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependencies.
FROM base as deps

# Copy package manager configuration and lock files first to leverage Docker caching
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Install dependencies
RUN pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

# Remove .npmrc after installation to secure
RUN rm -f .npmrc

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM deps as build

# Copy package manager configuration and lock files first to leverage Docker caching
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Install development dependencies
# RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .
# Run the build script.
RUN pnpm run build

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final

# Set environment variables.
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ARG ENV=production
ARG PORT=8020
ARG CLIENT=client1
ARG API_ENV=prod
ARG CURRENT_RELEASE_TAG=fallback-tag

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} \
    ENV=${ENV} \
    PORT=${PORT} \
    FEED_SOURCE=https://${CLIENT}-api-${API_ENV}.example.co.uk \
    CURRENT_RELEASE_TAG=${CURRENT_RELEASE_TAG}

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package.json .

# Copy the environment file.
RUN ls -la
COPY .env .env

# Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
# the built application from the build stage into the image
COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /usr/src/app/ ./

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8020

# Run the application.
CMD pnpm start

this is the error we get on Jenkins:
#12 [final 3/5] COPY .env .env
#12 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref b8dc9192-ad6a-45e2-b47b-b9c0625a2478::tnrbpv5dx0dd8lja68zz6akz2: "/.env": not found
------
 > [final 3/5] COPY .env .env:
------
dockerfile:74
--------------------
  72 |     # Copy the environment file.
  73 |     RUN ls -la
  74 | >>> COPY .env .env
  75 |     
  76 |     # Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref b8dc9192-ad6a-45e2-b47b-b9c0625a2478::tnrbpv5dx0dd8lja68zz6akz2: "/.env": not found

We have tried the following command:
COPY .env[t] .env

under the impression it would read the .env.defaults or .env.preview files, but this was not the case.
.env is not in dockerignore
We originally assumed the copy . . would have taken care of copying .env file too.
What would need to be done so on our feature branches the dockerfile reads the .env.defaults?

Do you have a file named exactly .env, or just different per-environment files?  You may need to inject the file at deploy time (or set environment variables without a file) instead of trying to build it into the image.

Solved this by removing the copy of .env from the docker side and setting the relevant .env variables through the Jenkins set up file.
